# Why doesn't handlebars {{#each}} rerender when reordering list?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to manage the sorted display of an array of objects based on a toggled property on a controller.  Because of this i'm unable to use the default `sortProperties` available to an `ArrayController`.

The expected result is that when I first click on the "edit" button i'm able to make changes to the items and when I click save it should re-render the `{{#each}}` block to show the new order of names.

Is this a bug in handlebars or am I doing something wrong?

JSBin: [Handlebars not re-rendering when property toggled](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vagonemo/5/edit?html,js,output)

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
 {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <h4>Raw \{{sorted_list}} property</h4>
    {{sorted_list}}<br/>
  <h4>Iterated `\{{#each item in sorted_list}}` property</h4>
  <ul>
    {{#each item in sorted_list}}
      {{#if editing}}
        <li>{{input type="text" value=item.name}}</li>
      {{else}}
        {{item.name}}<br/>
      {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{#if editing}}
    <button {{action "edit_stuff"}}>Save</button>
  {{else}}
    <button {{action "edit_stuff"}}>Edit</button>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {});

App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  toString: function() {
    return this.name;
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      App.Person.create({name: "Jules"}),
      App.Person.create({name: "Zed"}),
      App.Person.create({name: "Vincent"})
    ];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  editing: false,
  sorted_list: (function() {
    return this.sort_people();
  }).property('editing'),
  sort_people: function() {
    var sorted;
    sorted = this.get('content');
    sorted.sort(function(a, b) {
      return Ember.compare(a.name, b.name);
    });
    this.set('content', sorted);
    return sorted;
  },
  actions: {
    edit_stuff: function() {
      this.sort_people();
      this.toggleProperty('editing');
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it working like this

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    editing: false,
    sorted_list: (function() {
        return this.get('content').sortBy('name');
    }).property('editing'),
    actions: {
        edit_stuff: function() {
            this.toggleProperty('editing');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem i've been having with sortProperties is that it watches the property real time and the nature of ordering on an editable field makes this less than ideal.  I demonstrate the intended functionality in the JSBin i linked.

Comment: Then just disable sorting when you are entering `editting` mode.

Comment: disabling sorting unsorts all of our elements.